# How do I sort an array of objects by a particular field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, object

Sort object by value:

```
test": [{
    "position_order": 3,
},  {
    "position_order": 1,
}]
```

How can I sort this so that obviously the position_order 1 comes first in the array of objects?

Comment: [Array.prototype.sort documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - you pass a function that compares pairs of array entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.Prototype.Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) allows you to specify a comparison function.

```
test.sort(function(a, b) {
   if(a.position_order < b.position_order) {
      return -1;
   }
   if(b.position_order < a.position_order) {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
});
```

Comment: or you know, just `return a.position_order - b.position_order`

Comment: @Phil - yeah, sure, if you want to do it the easy way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy), an amazing JS library for manipulating collections, functions and objects. It works both in the client and in the server (Node.js).

That's how you do it with Underscore.

```
test = [{
    "position_order": 3,
},  {
    "position_order": 1,
}];
var ordered = _.sortBy(test, 'position_order');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the array sort function

```
var test = [{
"position_order": 3,
},  {
    "position_order": 1,
}];

test.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.position_order >= b.position_order ? 1 : -1
})
```

Comment: That's not how you should treat an equal sort position

Comment: @Phil The ECMAscript standard does not guarantee the behavior of a zero return - see the MDN desicription of Array.sort

Comment: Doesn't mean you shouldn't return `0` for an equal match